# How to remove the word 'Python' from plyer.notification?

Tags: python, notifications, package

Is there a way to remove this footer from the notification? I am using plyer.notification.

This is the code:

```
from plyer import notification

notification.notify(title='THIS IS THE TITLE', message='THIS IS THE MESSAGE', app_name='THIS IS THE APP NAME', app_icon='icon.ico', timeout=20)
```

This is the screenshot of the notification
[image: This is the screenshot of the notification]

Thank you